# How do I stop ERWin from creating UDT during Forward engineering

Tags: database-design

How can I stop ERWin from creating and using UDT (user defined data types) during the Forward engineering process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer taken from http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:FKGZJEF3aEoJ:lorf.ru/bol/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%87/ERWIN/DOC/Readme.txt+ERWIN+user+defined+datatypes&cd=18&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ie

### To prevent domains from being created as user-defined datatypes:

1. In the Domain Dictionary, in the Physical Edit Mode, click the General tab.
2. Select a domain from the Domain list and uncheck the User-Datatype check box, under the Domain Parent list.

Note: If the User Datatype box is NOT checked, the domain is not considered a user-defined datatype, which will cause the datatype of the domain to appear in the diagram as the datatype. If this box is checked, the domain is considered to be a user-defined datatype, which causes the domain name to display in the diagram as the datatype.

Hope this helps someone.